# javascript/jquery - crossbrowser detection when user is closing the browser?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

i'm looking for a reliable way on how to detect when a user closes the browser/tab in order to display a warning message (i'm having a shopping cart which uses sessions).

i've googled and couldn't find a proper solution - window.onunload will display a message every time i'm refreshing the page ..

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Alex & dk have you answered.. but if I may, this is dumb.  One of the key usage scenarios for tabs is to open multiple tabs per site.  The session won't go away until the entire browser is closed at any rate.

Answer (score 4):

You can't tell the difference between closing, reloading, back/forward etc.

`beforeunload` is fired on all of them.

Depending on if you launched the window yourself, you could run your code before calling `window.close()`, but this won't be called if the user closes the window themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe such a thing is possible.
The browser can fire an event when the page (un)loads, but who's to say wether the user is navigating, or closing the browser/tab?