# Run function if user close browser

Tags: javascript

I have problem with this function. I will explain - 
I must execute function if user closes browser. This function is write in JavaScript- saveCookieScriptPrefOnLogOut().

I have this solutions (I writed this using info from StackOverFlow):

```
var inFormOrLink;
$('a').live('click', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });
$('form').bind('submit', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(eventObject) {
var returnValue = undefined;
if (! inFormOrLink) {
    saveCookieScriptPrefOnLogOut();
}
saveCookieScriptPrefOnLogOut();
return true;
});
```

Problems with this solution is: every browser display windows with question "Do you really want to close?"

I have to hide this information/window. Second problem (less important but still) - FF and IE runs this function when I click on Link or form submit. I need to ignore a links and form submit.

solution must be crossbrowser solution (IE, Chrome, FF on windows. The most important is IE). I can use PHP and javascript.

Can you give me any answer how I solve these problems?

Comment: Why do you need to rely on the user closing the browser? Why can't you write that cookie when the page has finished loading? This is the wrong approach to development in a stateless environment like web pages.

Comment: here is  a similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107967/javascript-jquery-crossbrowser-detection-when-user-is-closing-the-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var inFormOrLink = false;

$('a').live('click', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });
$('form').live('submit', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    if( !inFormOrLink ) {
        saveCookieScriptPrefOnLogOut();
    }
});
```

If you return `undefined` from the event handler (no `return` statement implicitly returns `undefined`), the dialog will not appear.. Also, you called `saveCookieScriptPrefOnLogOut` regardless of `inFormOrLink`.